# Delete column on MariaDB slave

Tags: mariadb

I have a MariaDB 10.1 master/slave using InnoDB setup running on CentOS 7 which is mostly working as expected. However, somehow the slave has ended up with an extra column in a few tables. This column was deleted on the Master as part of the data import process but that change has not happened on the slave. The column is not required at all so I'd like to delete it.

So my question is (hopefully) simple: Can I safely delete the column directly on the slave without breaking replication?

Many thanks.

Comment: it should be fine. Worse case scenario you have to rebuild the standby.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can safely delete the extra column if you are sure it's not in the master.

But the bigger question is why didn't the change carry over to the slave, Any errors when you do a "show slave status" is the "seconds behind master" 0?

You might as well refresh the slave with a newer backup from the master to be sure everything is consistent.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. No errors and 0 seconds behind master.